# How to connect redux and apollo client together in a react app

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, graphql

i'm working on a project, and i'm using apollo/client, graphql in react, and for the global state management, i love using redux, but, before you say to me, why the hell am i using redux for, the reason for it, it's because i have to handle the data of the user in the login/register so i can put it in the localStorage, but not only for that, i'm quite sure i'll have to handle more data in my project so i'll put it in my store.

So, my question literally is, how to put the redux with apollo client, so i can use graphql to get data easily and if i have to store data, i can do it normally

i saw this way in the docs, but it didn't work for me, and the browser got mad at me and gave the error of, no Provider provided in the redux setup

```
import React from "react";
import App from "./App";

import { createStore } from "redux";
import reducer from "./reducer";

import {
  createHttpLink,
  InMemoryCache,
  ApolloProvider,
  ApolloClient
} from "@apollo/client";

const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: "http://localhost:5000"
});

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: httpLink,
  cache: new InMemoryCache()
});

const store = createStore(reducer);

export default (
  <ApolloProvider client={client} store={store}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
);
```

So, i decided to change the las part of the code to this, and it actually worked

```
<ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </ApolloProvider>
```

But if you go to settings, you'll see that ApolloProvider's child is the provider

[image]

So, could that cause a problem? is that the best way to connect redux and apollo/client ?

If you can help me to connect redux and apollo/client so i can use them normally, you're the greatest !

Thanks for your time ! .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't really "connect them together". You use both of them. And it works. But they don't have any real interaction as they don't know of each other - and they really don't need to have any interaction either.
What you are doing there, nesting different providers, is totally fine and is done in most apps. But as I said, that does not "connect" them in any way ;)